# How to Test a class and its method

Tags: python

New to Python, Got an error that i am unsure how to fix. Trying to answer a home work question. I am a bit confused on how to test the class and its methods, Which is part 2 of the question. Is there a special way of doing it?

> Write a class to represent a Product as per following specifications:
>
> Class name: Product (note uppercase "P")
>
> Define instance attributes as specified by the items in dictionary
>   object product2 i.e. discontinued, lead_time_days, etc.
>
> Define an **init**() method which initialises the instance attributes
>   to the value of the parameters passed to the method
>
> Define a set_product_name() method which sets the product_name in the
>   instance variable to the value of the parameter passed
>
> Define a get_product_details() method which returns the product
>   details formatted as "product_name - product_description"
>
> After having defined the class, you need to test the class and its
>   methods to show that it works. You can do this as follows:
>
> Instantiate an object of the class (name it prod) and pass product2 to
>   the initialiser (pass the whole product2 object, not individual
>   attributes)
>
> Set the product_name to something different by calling
>   set_product_name() and passing it an appropriate parameter
>
> Call get_product_details() to get the product name and description
>   (and print it)

Code:

```
product2 = {
    "discontinued": 0,
    "lead_time_days": 4,
    "product_category": "Personal Computers",
    "product_description": "8 inch Display (1920x1200) ...",
    "product_id": 104,
    "product_name": "NVIDIA SHIELD Tablet (WiFi)",
    "reorder_level": 10,
    "unit_price": 299.0
}
# My Code
class Product:
    def __init__(self, discontinued, lead_time_days, product_category, product_description, product_id, product_name, reorder_level, unit_price):
        self.discontinued = discontinued
        self.product_category = product_category
        self.product_description = product_description
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.reorder_level = reorder_level
        self.unit_price = unit_price

    def set_product_name(self, value):
        self.product_name = value

    def get_product_details(self):
        return self.product_name + " " + self.product_description
```

## Edit 1

I tried this but i know its wrong.

```
prod = Product(product2["discontinued"], product2["product_category"], product2['product_description'], product2['product_id'], product2['product_name'],product2['reorder_level'],product2['unit_price'])

prod.set_product_name('star')

print ('get_product_details'())
```

Comment: You don't show your whole code so we can't see how you are creating the object. 
Try something like (2 lines)  x = Product(0, 4, 'Personal Computers', '8 inch', 104, 'Nvidia', 10, 299.0) and then print product.get_product_details()

Comment: Edited my original post, not sure if that will help.

Answer (score 3):

Pro tip: use unpacking to deliver keyword arguments to a class method.

This can be done by changing your class to the following:

```
class Product:
    def __init__(self, discontinued=None, lead_time_days=None, product_category=None, product_description=None, product_id=None, product_name=None, reorder_level=None, unit_price=None):
        self.discontinued = discontinued
        self.product_category = product_category
        self.product_description = product_description
        self.product_id = product_id
        self.product_name = product_name
        self.reorder_level = reorder_level
        self.unit_price = unit_price

    def set_product_name(self, value):
        self.product_name = value

    def get_product_details(self):
        return self.product_name + " " + self.product_description
```

By giving your arguments default values (e.g. discontinued=None) it makes them keyword arguments. This is helpful if you have a dictionary or a large number of inputs to a function.

To create the object/instantiate the class you can call:

```
obj = Product(**product2)
```

**product2 basically means:

```
discontinued=0,lead_time_days=4,product_category="Personal Computers",product_description="8 inch Display (1920x1200) ...",product_id=104,product_name="NVIDIA SHIELD Tablet (WiFi)",reorder_level=10,unit_price=299.0
```

After the object is instantiated you call its methods using dot notation:

```
obj.set_product_name('new name')
print(obj.get_product_details())
```

Comment: Whoa. That's amazing, I didn't know you could do that with dictionary keys. What happens if there isn't a 1 for 1 match between the class keywords and the dict keys? Will it do as many as possible, or will it error out?

Answer (score 1):

`product2` can be passed as [kwargs](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/args_and_kwargs.html) dict.

Then you can call your function for the instance you created:

```
prod = Product(**product2)
prod.set_product_name('star')
print (prod.get_product_details())
star 8 inch Display (1920x1200) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Your testing code doesn't comply to the requirement "pass the whole product2 object, not individual attributes". You pass individual attributes:

```
prod = Product(product2["discontinued"], product2["product_category"], product2['product_description'], product2['product_id'], product2['product_name'],product2['reorder_level'],product2['unit_price'])
```

**2.** The [setattr(object, name, value)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr) function will be handy in your case.

**My solution:**

```
product2 = { 
    "discontinued": 0,
    "lead_time_days": 4,
    "product_category": "Personal Computers",
    "product_description": "8 inch Display (1920x1200) ...",
    "product_id": 104,
    "product_name": "NVIDIA SHIELD Tablet (WiFi)",
    "reorder_level": 10, 
    "unit_price": 299.0
}

class Product:
    def __init__(self, specification):
        for key, value in specification.items():
            setattr(self, key, value) 

    def set_product_name(self, value):
        self.product_name = value

    def get_product_details(self):
        return f'{self.product_name} - {self.product_description}'

###Test
# Instantiate an object of the class (name it prod) and pass product2 to
# the initialiser (pass the whole product2 object, not individual attributes)
prod = Product(product2)

# Set the product_name to something different by calling set_product_name()
# and passing it an appropriate parameter
prod.set_product_name('Another Tablet')

# Call get_product_details() to get the product name and
# description (and print it)
print(prod.get_product_details())
```